# Inserting a variable in a formula in Visual Basic

Tags: excel, vba, variables, formula, basic

Hi I'm trying to insert a variable into a formula in Visual Basic:

```
Dim alpha As Double

Range("E3:E14").Value = "=E2 + alpha"
```

What I'm trying to do is insert a formula for E3 that is the number above it (E2) plus a variable (like .5) and copy that formula down to E14.

So for E5 it would be = E4 + alpha

Thanks in advance

Comment: `"alpha"` is just a string literal. VBA will only ever treat a string literal as a string literal. If you mean to concatenate `alpha`'s **value** into the formula, then take it out of the string literal: `.Value = "=E2 + " & alpha`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working model:

```
Sub poiunt()
    Dim alpha As Double
    alpha = 5
    Range("E3").Formula = "=E2 +" & alpha
    Range("E3").Copy Range("E4:E15")
End Sub
```